# Creating a Testnet node ( stake pool ) on Ras Pi

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

I did watch this series on YT for Ras Pi - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBdpE1ta1EU&list=PLBhbLwOuj0DfTnneuG3vyoDHY7Dv_aiyq&index=10

But I have a doubt about the updated method.

Is Cabal better or Nix, while creating a Cardano testnet node on Cardano?

Please suggest and re-direct to the right config. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For getting started on a testnet it is best to look at the up-to-date guide https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/getting-started